# Streaming to Facebook Live API not working?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have integrated Facebook live streaming in my iOS app and it was correctly working previously but from 1st May not working.Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Below is working code before May :
func start() {

```
    guard FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_video") else {
        return self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didErrorWith: FBSDKLiveVideo.errorFromDescription(description: "The \"publish_video\" permission has not been granted"))
    }
    print("Parameters : \(self.audience)")
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(self.audience)/live_videos", parameters: self.createParameters, httpMethod: "POST")
   // let m=FBSDKAccessToken.current().appID
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        _ = graphRequest?.start { (_, result, error) in
            guard error == nil, let dict = (result as? NSDictionary) else {
                return self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didErrorWith: FBSDKLiveVideo.errorFromDescription(description: "Error initializing the live video session: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))"))
            }

            self.url = URL(string:(dict.value(forKey: "stream_url") as? String)!)
            self.id = dict.value(forKey: "id") as? String
            self.videoId = dict.value(forKey: "id") as? String
            guard let streamPath = self.url?.lastPathComponent, let query = self.url?.query else {
                return self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didErrorWith: FBSDKLiveVideo.errorFromDescription(description: "The stream path is invalid"))
            }

            self.session.startRtmpSession(withURL: "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/", andStreamKey: "\(streamPath)?\(query)") 

            self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didStartWith:self.session)
        }
    }
}
```

I have also asked this question Facebook Support team they have suggested to use rtmps then I have updated my code as below then also not working:
 func start() {

```
    guard FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_video") else {
        return self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didErrorWith: FBSDKLiveVideo.errorFromDescription(description: "The \"publish_video\" permission has not been granted"))
    }
    print("Parameters : \(self.audience)")
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(self.audience)/live_videos", parameters: self.createParameters, httpMethod: "POST")
   // let m=FBSDKAccessToken.current().appID
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        _ = graphRequest?.start { (_, result, error) in
            guard error == nil, let dict = (result as? NSDictionary) else {
                return self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didErrorWith: FBSDKLiveVideo.errorFromDescription(description: "Error initializing the live video session: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))"))
            }

            self.url = URL(string:(dict.value(forKey: "stream_url") as? String)!)
            self.id = dict.value(forKey: "id") as? String
            self.videoId = dict.value(forKey: "id") as? String
            guard let streamPath = self.url?.lastPathComponent, let query = self.url?.query else {
                return self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didErrorWith: FBSDKLiveVideo.errorFromDescription(description: "The stream path is invalid"))
            }
            self.session.startRtmpSession(withURL: "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/", andStreamKey: "\(streamPath)?\(query)")
            self.delegate.liveVideo(self, didStartWith:self.session)
        }
    }
}
```

Not Woking can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What means "Not working" ? Any message, error?

Comment: I have debug my iOS app then I am seeing below can check response here:

Stream Url : Optional(rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/122721352285815?s_bl=1&s_sml=0&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=AbwPTyfTbuxnDDb-)
Connecting:live-api-s.facebook.com:443, stream name:122721352285815?s_bl=1&s_sml=0&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=AbwPTyfTbuxnDDb-
ClientState: 1
ClientState: 2
ClientState: 3
Want read:4096, read:7
Want s0, but not:0x15
Want read:4089, read:0
Read from stream error:0
ClientState: 11
~RTMPSession